# Can I use both PrintWriter and BufferedOutputStream on the same outputstream?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

Can I use both PrintWriter and BufferedOutputStream on the same outputstream?

The situation is this:

I'm having a SSLSocket program and I want to be able to transfer both Strings and byte [] over the socket at different points in time easily without having to cast byte [] to string etc, however, PrintWriter only allows me to transfer Strings and BufferedOutputStream only allows me to transfer bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PrintWriter is just a wrapper around original OutputStream.
BufferedOutputStream is a wrapper around OutputStream too.
So you can use both. Why not?

Single thing you should to consider - you should be carefull working with both stream and writer in multithread environment because you can get unpredictable result.

The java.io.Writer class (super class for PrintWriter) use itself as a lock object. So you can also probably use it to synchronize multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

That's ok, but you have to make sure to flush them in the right order. You can also use the `PrintWriter` on top of the `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: On the same account, I can use both Scanner and BufferedInputStream on the same InputStream?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a DataOutputStream (possibly wrapping a BufferedOutputStream). It allows you to transfer `byte[]`, `int`, `double` `String` and many other types. To send the `byte[]` you may want to send the length first as a `int` or `short`.